# x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

Tags: javascript

```
x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
```

i don't understand what "***.value***" means?
i have already tried to find solution from google and past questions of javascript.
so please tell explanation for better understanding.

Comment: `.value` means get the string assigned to the `value` attribute on the element `#numb`.

Comment: like text in input field

Comment: I suggest you read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) if you need a tutorial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`.value` means that you get the value assigned to a HTML element.  For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getName()
                {
                    var x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
                    msgbox(x);
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='button' value='Get Name' onclick='getName()'/>
        <input id='numb' type='text' name='myname' value='5'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note, the `value` *property* has **nothing** to do with the `value` *attribute* - which is HTML.  An element with no `value` attribute will still have a `.value` property.  Also, `checkbox`-es and the like will have **default** *values* which the .`value` property will find, but aren't written in the HTML `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`value` here is a [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)) of the [Element Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) returned by [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp).

As [you can see at this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp), this is a property of almost all HTML form elements, such as `<input>` fields.